# How would I loop an integer to find a specific number of multiples?

Tags: java, loops

So im trying to create a program that will get an input and then find a specific number of multiples the user wants from it. For example, we can say the user puts in 4, and wants 6 multiples of it. The biggest problem i have with this, is simply just starting it! I understand that this will involve loops, but i dont get how to make it work if the user would want like 100 or something.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "6 multiples"? What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: That's actually what developers should do, take an idea and implement it in code, no one told that it's gonna be simple. You should find the solution yourself.

Comment: so if the user put in 4, and wanted 6 multiples, i would expect the output to be 4, 8,12,16,20, and 24

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve problems like this is to get out a piece of paper and pen/pencil and do several examples by hand. Let's assume that your program is called Foo, if you ran:

```
Foo 2 6
```

You would expect the get 6 multiples of 2 (the first 6?) as output, which are:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
```

if you ran:

```
Foo 3 10
```

You would expect the 10 multiples of 3 as output, which are:

```
3, 6, 9, 12 , 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30
```

You should be able to see a pattern between these two calls and their output. The first multiple is *always* the number itself and the last multiple is *always* the product of the two arguments you pass to `Foo`. From here you should easily be able to create a loop over that range. (i.e. From 2 to 12 or From 3 to 30)